# Compiling C for ARMv7 with MH_EXECUTE

Tags: ios8, clang++, armv7

(environment: jailbroken iOS 8.3, iPad 2)

Currently I'm successfully compiling a hello world program with clang like this:

```
clang -c test.c -target armv7-macho
```

(compiling on a Windows 7 machine)

However, when I check the Mach-O header of the file, the `filetype` is `MH_OBJECT`, not `MH_EXECUTE`.

**I need clang to output an executable file (`MH_EXECUTE`) and not an object (`MH_OBJECT`) so I can sign it with `ldid` and run it.** How can I do that? Is there a switch for it? Does clang even support it?

(What I'm trying is to get very basic C code to run on the device, as in go to terminal, write `./binary` and run it; no need for app/tweak/whatsoever)

Comment: Why are you using the `-c` switch if you don't want an object file output?

Comment: @Mat the tutorial I was following said so and I didn't realize! I just tried without `-c`, but now I'm getting a `ld` error: `unrecognized switch -dynamic`